# How to post list of object in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have seen several tutorials in which to send a json object with POST method.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> createEntity([FromBody]Entity entity)
{
    try
    {
         await _repository.Entity.CreateEntityAsync(entity);
         return Ok();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
      }
}
```

This does the job correctly

Now if I want to send:

> {
>   "ID":1,
>   "data":[
>       {
>           "value1":"xxxx",
>           "value2":"yyyy"
>       },
>       {
>           "value1":"zzzz",
>           "value2":"wwww"
>       }
>   ]
>   }

if you could recommend me what would be the best option to work this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a DTO class as follows:

```
public class YourDto
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public List<Data> Data {get; set;}
}
```

Where `Data` is as follows:

```
public class Data
{
   public string Value1 {get; set;}
   public string Value2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> createEntity([FromBody]YourDto yourDto)
{
    try
    {
         // do whatever you want to do with the yourDto object

         return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```